# How can make a PROCEDURE to read a customized function?

Tags: oracle, plsql

[image]

How can make a PROCEDURE to read a customized function?

I have a picture attached in the question.

Type of error is `2208  PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'TESTING'`

I do not know if this have to be because I am looking for a `DATE`.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: TYPE OF ERROR IS : 2208 PLS-00049: Bad bind variable 'TESTING'

Comment: It's not the fact that it's a user-defined (not "customized") function. Try adding any two dates together and see what happens. Also, http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, and http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails

Answer (score 3):

Function you wrote returns `DATE`.

Procedure uses that function and has `SYSDATE + FUNCTION_VALUE`, which evaluates to `DATE + DATE`. What is the result of (dd.mm.yyyy) `06.08.2018 + 25.12.2018`? None. Error. Function should return `NUMBER`, or - if it has to return a `DATE` value, then you should add a number to it, not `SYSDATE` (or any other kind of a *date).

Besides, posting the question as an image is really a bad idea. You should have posted code as *code*, straight here.